# Is there a synergistic effect between phosphate and testosterone in respect to Physiology?

Tags: blood-tests, endocrinology, practice-of-medicine, testosterone

For example: A patient's blood analysis results come through, and it states that the patient has high testosterone and high phosphate levels.

What are the likely causes of this, assuming/acknowledging that environmental factors etc, are not contributing factors to the results and the thyroid gland is correctly functioning?

However, the condition of the parathyroid gland is unknown. Would it be a proper first response to rule out the possibility of a malfunctioning parathyroid gland via further testing?

Comment: I was a bit confused by your question, especially the title in relation to the body. I edited it -  can you take a look and see whether this is what you are asking and maybe take another look at the title?

Comment: Essentially I was asking if Phosphate levels affect testosterone levels or visa versa. I'm too sure how to word it, in all honesty. On that note, should I delete it?

Comment: I don't think we're at a point where deletion is called for. It just needs some explanation what the connection between "is there a synergistic effect between tostesterone and phosphate" and "should the parathyroid gland be tested" is. I'm just a bit confused :-)

Comment: Ah, I see. *The parathyroid gland helps to maintain the Phosphate levels*, and I was wondering if Phosphate and Testosterone "work together" so much so, that if there a lack of Phosphate would that be correlated with a lower testosterone level and visa versa